# TKinter Popup Progress Bar

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to make a popup progress bar that shows the progress of some files downloading after a button is clicked.  I can execute the command linked with the button perfectly, but I am struggling to create a popup progress bar.

Here is what I have so far

```
 def button_command(self):
    #start progress bar
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Label(popup, text="Files being downloaded").grid(row=0,column=0)

    progress = 0
    progress_var = tk.DoubleVar()
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(popup, variable=progress_var, maximum=100)
    progress_bar.grid(row=1, column=0)#.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1, side=tk.BOTTOM)
    popup.pack_slaves()

    progress_step = float(100.0/len(teams))
    for team in self.teams:

        self.do_work()


        progress += progress_step
        progress_var.set(progress)
        popup.update_idletasks()


    return 0
```

It's creating a popup window currently, but there is nothing in it.  If anyone has experience with this, the help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is due to the position of `update_idletasks` in your for loop. You call it after the first call to `self.do_work`, so the GUI with the progressbar is only updated/displayed after the task is completed. At least, that's what I experienced by testing your code with `time.sleep` instead of `do_work`. You should therefore start by updating the GUI before launching the first task. I also noticed that the progressbar was displayed sooner when I used `update` instead of `update_idletasks`, but I don't know why.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

teams = range(100)

def button_command():
    #start progress bar
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Label(popup, text="Files being downloaded").grid(row=0,column=0)

    progress = 0
    progress_var = tk.DoubleVar()
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(popup, variable=progress_var, maximum=100)
    progress_bar.grid(row=1, column=0)#.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1, side=tk.BOTTOM)
    popup.pack_slaves()

    progress_step = float(100.0/len(teams))
    for team in teams:
        popup.update()
        sleep(5) # lauch task
        progress += progress_step
        progress_var.set(progress)

    return 0

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="Launch", command=button_command).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: While that change from update_idletasks to just update may seem minor, it fixed the issue for me!  Appreciate the help